# How to fill the index in Pandas Pivot_table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I use pandas.pivot_table to show the following DataFrame:

```
A  B
a    SH     1.0
b    BJ     2.0
     SH     3.0
c    BJ    10.0
     SH     5.0
```

So I want to change the DataFrame to the following, I mean to fill the 
blanks in the index:

```
A  B
a    SH     1.0
b    BJ     2.0
b    SH     3.0
c    BJ    10.0
c    SH     5.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary, only `pandas` display `MultiIndex` this way.

You can change it by [`multi_sparse`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options):

```
#temporaly display it
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)

A  B 
a  SH     1.0
b  BJ     2.0
b  SH     3.0
c  BJ    10.0
c  SH     5.0
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

For write to excel get joined cells together:

```
df.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

[image: one]

Possible solution is [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then not write default index by `index=False`:

```
df.reset_index().to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: two]

Comment: But I need it to export the DataFrame to Excel, is it possible to fill the blanks in the index?

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!